# joining tables with where clause

Tags: mysql

I am having two tables, the structure is given below

Table 1

- schid
- name
- cost
- type

Table 2

- schid
- details
- oldcost

I am unable to write a query to display records from table 2 of let suppose type A OR B (Here as you can see type field is in table 1), Here one more thing to add is that schid is not a primary key, The query which i am executing is retrieving more records than expected, I think due to join, Can i execute it without using join

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.schid=Table2.schid
WHERE Table1.type='A'
  OR Table1.type='B'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help:

```
SELECT t2.schid, t2.details, t2.oldcost
FROM Table2 t2
   JOIN Table1 t1
      ON t1.schid = t2.schid
WHERE t1.type IN ('A', 'B');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should retrieve only the table 2 records which match the criteria.

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.schid = t2.schid
WHERE t1.type = 'A'
 OR t1.type = 'B';
```

Comment: i tried this query it work to some extent, But there is an issue schid is not a primary key, And as a result i am retrieving more records than expected

Comment: Since table 2 does not have type field, so one need to use type field from table 1.  The only common field to both the table is schid.  It makes sense to use schid to join both the tables.  Since schid is not a primary key, it is difficult to suggest a solution without additional information of your  expected result.   If your concern is that the query returns duplicate records, use distinct keyword in the select statement to remove them.  Failing to use join will result in Cartesian product i.e., query will return more records than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM `Table2` t2
JOIN `Table1` t1 ON t2.`schid`=t1.`schid`
WHERE t1.`type` IN ('A','B');
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)